# Reboot inside rescue mode chroot

Tags: debian, chroot, rescuemode

I had a problem booting my computer, so I ran a Live cd and booted it into rescue mode, started SSH and went back home, then I fixed the boot error remotely, and now I want to restart my server so that I can boot my system, but when I try to run any of the following commands I get an error saying :

```
root@debian:~# reboot
Running in chroot, ignoring request.

root@debian:~# shutdown -r 0
Running in chroot, ignoring request.
```

So, my question is : **Is it possible for me to restart my server from inside the chroot?**

Comment: have you tried exiting the chroot, or just ssh-ing in again on a second terminal?

Comment: use command `exit` to exit chroot and then reboot

Comment: I have the same problem, provide chroot with root privileges.

Answer (score 3):

For others who need this, there are a number of possible work-arounds. Some may not apply to your situation.

1. Connect via another ssh session and `reboot`, as *cas* suggested.
2. Type `exit` to leave the chroot and `reboot`, as *Krzysztof Stasiak* suggested.
3. From within the chroot, `ssh localhost` and `reboot` (similar to #1 above).
4. The [servicectl project on GitHub](https://github.com/smaknsk/servicectl) is a "bash script start/stop service (daemons) for linux using systemd in chroot". (Systemd is the reason `reboot` is failing.) I haven't tried this myself.
5. Type `echo b |sudo tee /proc/sysrq-trigger`. Use this as a last resort, as I'm not sure it will flush files to disk.

Comment: I have to clarify a bit the last resort option. Sending `b` to `/proc/sysrq-trigger` will NOT trigger sync/unmount, it's distinct operations. So you should send `s` (sync), then `u` (remount readonly) and `b` at last, having to wait each of that operations to complete. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysrq.html -- there's a good description.

Comment: The 5 messed up my entire system, I sended the s and u options first tho.